# How can a user see the whole text in the textfield or the textformfield?

Tags: flutter

I have a TextFormField where the user can edit text. While editing the text, I want the user to see the whole text that he has entered. Is there a way to do this? Currently only one line of the text is visible while editing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use multilines property.

```
TextField(
  keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
  maxLines: null,
)
```

You can also set 'maxLines' to say 3 if you desire maximum 3 lines in the user input.

Comment: What is `maxLines` by default?

Comment: The default value is 1. That's the reason you are able to write only one line in the textfield by default. You can also set to say 3 in case you desire max 3 lines in the use input.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `keyboardType` attribute of TextField and `maxLines` (null for auto wrap):

```
    TextField(
       keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
       maxLines: <max_lines_number>
    )
```